# Closed form for the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, means, elliptic-integrals

Let's consider the function defined by the integral:

$$R(a,b,c,d)=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)}}$$

I'm interested in the case $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Obviously, the function is symmetric in all four parameters.

This function has some really nice properties.

$$R(ka,kb,kc,kd)=\frac{1}{k} R(a,b,c,d)$$

Thus:

$$R(a,a,a,a)=\frac{1}{a}$$

Moreover:

$$R(a,a,b,b)=\frac{\ln a-\ln b}{a-b}$$

This is the reciprocal of the logarithmic mean of the numbers $a$ and $b$.

For the case of $R(a,a,b,c)$ we can use the Euler substitution to obtain:

$$R(a,a,b,c)=2 \int_{\sqrt{bc}-a}^{\frac{b+c}{2}-a} \frac{dt}{t^2-(a-b)(a-c)}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a-b)(a-c)}} \left( \ln \frac{\sqrt{(a-b)(a-c)}+\sqrt{bc}-a}{\sqrt{(a-b)(a-c)}-\sqrt{bc}+a}-\ln \frac{\sqrt{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{b+c}{2}-a}{\sqrt{(a-b)(a-c)}-\frac{b+c}{2}+a} \right)$$

---

As far as I see, this function is deeply related to various means (you can see arithmetic, geometric and logarithmic means represented in the above expressions).

> Is there a closed form for the general case of $R(a,b,c,d)$ for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^+$? Perhaps, in terms of hypergeometric functions or elliptic integrals?

Comment: ellipic integrals. byrd and friedman will give u the formula you need

Comment: this is almost the definition of the incomplete elliptic integral

Comment: @Startwearingpurple, what does that mean? IEI has only three parameters, not four

Comment: any integral of the form $\int dx1/\sqrt{Q(x)}$ where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of order $4$ or $3$ might be calculated in terms of rational functions and elliptic integrals. As i said, consult 
https://books.google.de/books?id=xFTsCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=byrd+friedman+elliptic&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio8IDN6KfOAhXI1SwKHQBCD14Q6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=byrd%20friedman%20elliptic&f=false

Comment: @You'reInMyEye One should first do a fractional linear change of variables $x=\frac{\alpha t+\beta}{\gamma t+\delta}$ and choose the parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ so that we have $(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)$ under square root.

Comment: @Startwearingpurple, then it will not be the general case of independent $a,b,c,d$. I understand that it will be a simple elliptic integral in some particular cases, thank you

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5B1%2F((Sqrt(a%2Bx)*Sqrt(b%2Bx)*Sqrt(c%2Bx)*Sqrt(d%2Bx))%5D

Comment: See $\mathbf{3.147}$ in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik Table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

---

**Hint:**

Assume that $0<a<b<c<d$. Using the magical linear-fractional transformation,

$$\frac{\left(d-b\right)\left(x+a\right)}{\left(d-a\right)\left(x+b\right)}=t,$$

we obtain:

$$\begin{align}
R{\left(a,b,c,d\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\left(x+a\right)\left(x+b\right)\left(x+c\right)\left(x+d\right)}}\\
&=\small{\int_{\frac{a\left(d-b\right)}{b\left(d-a\right)}}^{\frac{d-b}{d-a}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{\frac{\left(d-a\right)\left(b-a\right)t}{\left(d-b\right)-\left(d-a\right)t}\cdot\frac{\left(d-b\right)\left(b-a\right)}{\left(d-b\right)-\left(d-a\right)t}\cdot\frac{\left(d-a\right)\left(d-b\right)\left(1-t\right)\left[\left(d-b\right)\left(c-a\right)-\left(d-a\right)\left(c-b\right)t\right]}{\left[\left(d-b\right)-\left(d-a\right)t\right]^{2}}}}\cdot\frac{\left(d-a\right)\left(d-b\right)\left(b-a\right)}{\left[\left(d-b\right)-\left(d-a\right)t\right]^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{a\left(d-b\right)}{b\left(d-a\right)}}^{\frac{d-b}{d-a}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)\left[\left(d-b\right)\left(c-a\right)-\left(d-a\right)\left(c-b\right)t\right]}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(d-b\right)\left(c-a\right)}}\int_{\frac{a\left(d-b\right)}{b\left(d-a\right)}}^{\frac{d-b}{d-a}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)\left[1-\frac{\left(d-a\right)\left(c-b\right)}{\left(d-b\right)\left(c-a\right)}t\right]}}.\\
\end{align}$$

The rest is pretty straightforward. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes, I can. Great answer! Thank you

Comment: Now I see what @Startwearingpurple meant! We set $\sqrt{t}=u$ and get incomplete elliptic integral immediately

Comment: How do you come up with these divine rational substitutions?